# CMake automatically appending -O2 flag

Tags: gcc, cmake, android-ndk, clang, compiler-flags

I am working on an android native project. I have this configuration in my `build.gradle`

```
externalNativeBuild {

            cmake {
                arguments "--warn-uninitialized",
                        "-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang",
                        "-DANDROID_STL=c++_shared",
                        "-DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-21",
                        "-DAPP_ALLOW_MISSING_DEPS=true",
                        "-DSHARED_LIBRARY=1",
                        "-DOFFLINE_SYNC_SUPPORT_ENABLED=0",
                        "-DT5_TARGET_PLATFORM=Android",
                        "-DVERSION_STANDARD=14",
                        "-DREQUIRED_STANDARD=OFF",
                        "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release"
                cFlags "-Werror=return-type", "-Wno-pragmas", "-DBOOST_THREAD_PROVIDES_FUTURE",
                        "-DBOOST_THREAD_PROVIDES_FUTURE_CONTINUATION",
                        "-DJPEG_DISABLE_OPTIM -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=32",
                        "-mno-unaligned-access",
                        "-Wno-extern-c-compat"
                cppFlags "-Os", "-Wno-conversion-null", "-fexceptions", "-frtti", "-std=c++14", "-DES_ENABLE_LOGGING"


            }
```

After build when I check `build.ninja` file, I see that `CMake` is appending some flags automatically including `-O2`:

```
build CMakeFiles/myapp.dir/native-lib.cpp.o: CXX_COMPILER__myapp_Release /Users/vmangal/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication2/app/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp || cmake_object_order_depends_target_myapp
  DEFINES = -Dmyapp_EXPORTS
  DEP_FILE = CMakeFiles/myapp.dir/native-lib.cpp.o.d
  FLAGS = -g -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -Os -Wno-conversion-null -fexceptions -frtti -std=c++14 -DES_ENABLE_LOGGING -O2 -DNDEBUG  -fPIC
  OBJECT_DIR = CMakeFiles/myapp.dir
  OBJECT_FILE_DIR = CMakeFiles/myapp.dir
```

As it can be seen in flags, `-O2` flag is appended:

```
-Os -Wno-conversion-null -fexceptions -frtti -std=c++14 -DES_ENABLE_LOGGING -O2 -DNDEBUG  -fPIC
```

Actually , I want to decrease size of lib. `-Os` option seems to be overridden by `-O2` option. Is there a way to tell `CMake` not to append such flags.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/android/ndk/issues/378. This is how CMake behaves. Less specific flags come before more specific flags. You're adding your optimization flags to the generic `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` variable instead of the build mode specific `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE`.

`cFlags` and `cppFlags` generally don't behave well IME. Either set the appropriate CMake variables in `arguments` with `-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE` (or whatever build mode), or set them in your CMakeLists.txt. Option 2 is better IMO because it keeps your C++ build config in one place.

Comment: Also If I set set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE="-Os") , I see that DNDEBUG flag is removed. Is there a way to only append "-Os" flag to already set flags.

Comment: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/list.html#modification